# Transferring SSH keys

Tags: server, ssh, mac

4 months ago I generated a public key from Ubuntu operation system to be used in github. Recently, I bought a new mac laptop, and I am thinking of using the same public key. Is there a way to transfer the key I generated from Ubuntu to mac? and how?

Regards,
Arwa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Look for the generated keys under `~/.ssh`

After copy, you need to set permission of your private key to `600` or `400` in order to use it.

Comment: There is no need to change permissions. I just did it.

Comment: Yes, if the permission remain 600 or 400 then no need to change it

Comment: You **MUST** ensure that the permissions are `600` or `400`. Most `ssh` clients won't accept the key otherwise, and even then, this is a major security issue!